# derivative of expected value of maximum of two stochastics variables (iid)

Tags: probability, integration, stochastic-integrals, maximum-principle

I need to optimize an expected value of a maximum value for $q$. The problem has three variables, $q$ is a constant and $D_1$ and $D_2$ are stochastic variables with pdf $f(x)$ and cdf $F(x)$. The stochastic variables are i.i.d.

On Stackoverflow there are more problems like this but there $f(x)$ is known and mostly uniform, in my case this is not true.

To maximize I want to take the FOC, to do so I first rewrite the expected value as an integral. However, I saw that Im not able to take the derivative of the resulting integral.

$$
E[\max(q-D_1-D_2, 0)] = \int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty \max(q-x-y, 0)f(x)f(y)\,dx\,dy \\
= \int_0^q\int_0^{q-y} (q-x-y)f(x)f(y)\,dx\,dy\\
= \int_0^q\int_0^{q-y} qf(x)f(y)\,dx\,dy  - \int_0^q\int_0^{q-y} xf(x)f(y)\,dx\,dy - \int_0^q\int_0^{q-y} yf(x)f(y)\,dx\,dy
$$

How can I now get $\dfrac{\partial E[\max(q-D_1-D_2, 0)]}{\partial q}$?

Note, the derivative will never be zero since a higher $ q $ will lead to a higher expected value. However, in my real problem the function exist of several parts and only the part which is shown here gives difficulties for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Z=q-Y-X$. Then, we are concerned with $E[max(Z,0)]$.

$P(max(Z,0) > c) $ is obviously $1$ if $c <0$. If $c \geq 0$, $P(max(Z,0) >c) = P(Z>c) = 1-F_Z(c)$. Thus, the cdf of $max(Z,0)$ is $F(c) = \left\{ \begin{array}{lr} 0, c <0 \\ F_z(c), c \geq 0 \end{array} \right.$.

Now, use the area rule for expectation (i.e. $E[X] = \int_0^\infty (1-F_X(x)) dx$ for non-negative r.v.'s $X$) to find $E[\max(Z,0)] = \int_0^\infty (1-F(c)) dc = \int_0^\infty (1-F_Z(c)) dc $.

You can easily calculate the CDF or PDF of $Z$ on your own. Note that the distribution of $\max(Z,0)$ is a point mass with probability $F_Z(0)$ at $0$ and density matching $Z$ for values greater than zero, and zero otherwise. So, if you have the density of $Z$,  $E[\max(Z,0)]=\int_0^\infty z f(z) dz$ (since the mass at $0$ doesn't contribute anything to the expectation).

Comment: I'm convinced by your answer. Only, how can I get the derivative of the last intergral to $q$ without specifing $ f_z$ explicit? This since $f_D$ is not know explicit in this stage.

Comment: The density of $X+Y$ is $f_d * f_d (c)$ where $*$ denotes convolution. The density of $X+Y - q$ is thus $f_d * f_d (c-q)$, and thus the density of $q-Y-X$ is $f_Z(z) = f_d * f_d (q-z)$. Then assuming appropriate conditions (differentiability of $f_d$ and say $f_d$,$f_d'$ are continuous), use differentiation under the integral - you'd have to know something about $f_d$ to justify that this is possible. Note $(f_d * f_d)' = f_d' * f_d$.